# How to Implement Trap Damage Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, platformer

Currently, I have a 2D platformer game, and I want to implement a function that can make the player die and go back to the start or a checkpoint when he interacts with a weapon or trap.

What I have in my scene is a sprite with a `Rigidbody` on it and a trap sprite with a `BoxCollider2D` on it which is set to trigger.

How can I make my player go back to the start when he hits the trap?

Comment: Are you keeping track of the checkpoints? Do you need to reset the scene (dead monster respawn/ you loose earned items/ etc)?

Comment: I want to reset to the closet checkpoints t however I do that. I don't need to worry about items

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not need to reset the scene, all you need to do is

- Save the transform of the last checkpoint when you reach it.
- Destroy the current player.
- Instantiate the current player around the saved transform.
- Move the camera back to the player if it not done already.

Comment: the camera follows the paltry, so how do I make the trap do damage

Comment: do I put a script on the trap that kills the player or do I need something on the player

Comment: may I ask how I do any of that as I'm very new to unity

Comment: Start with the Unity 2D platform tutorial to get some basics and ask a clear question where you struggle when you try to implement it on your own (with the error and what you did)

Answer (score 0):

Add this script into your enemy. It will reset the scene which in theory will bring the player back to start. Remember to call the `UnityEngine` and `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` API services at the start. Also, make sure to have the player tag on the player, so the scene won’t restart if **any** GameObject collides with the enemy.

```
  // Initiates when something collides with enemy
        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
    
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag(“Player”))
           {
              SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.getActiveScene().buildIndex);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Though the question asks to go to a checkpoint, which could be part from the scene that is not the same as when you load the scene the first time.

Comment: One of your { is at the wrong place, not enough to make it possible to edit it. And yes, the tutorial works because it has a GameManager instance that saves the transform of the checkpoint and loads that one on scene reload.

Comment: ill have 1 scene

Comment: @elliot727 What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I load everything g together

Comment: @elliot727 Oh ok, I get you now. This script will only reload the scene that you put the enemy in, so it will load only one scene.

Comment: @elliot727 Did that help?

Comment: @noobprogrammer I get this error SceneManager' does not contain a definition for 'getActiveScene'

Comment: @elliot727 Did you make sure to put `UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the very top of your script? This finds the definition for that.